# How to correct a typeError Settings is null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, settings

I develop an application in angular, And I want testing my application with files spec.
But when I launch the file spec I have an error
"TypeError: settings is null in http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/vendor.js (line 163664)"

I start with angular so I have any idea to correct my problem

modal-result-training.component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IAttempt } from '../../models/attempt.model';
import { ITraining } from '../../models/training.model';
import { ModalResultTrainingComponent } from './modal-result-training.component';
import { OpinionsService } from 'app/feature/elearning-training/services/opinions.service';
import { EntityService } from '@core/services/entity.service';
import { FireModule } from '../../../../@core/fire/fire/fire.module';
import { UserService } from '@core/services/user.service';
import { NbAclService } from '@nebular/security';
import { NbAuthModule } from '@nebular/auth';
import { NbDialogModule, NbThemeModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DialogService } from '@core/services/dialog.service';

const training = {
  id: 'ZGtz6yrEemCNTo5KAytu',
  refProject: 'JGvD1faO8L2vWb66BQ87',
  publicationDate: new Date(),
  version: 1,
  name: 'My project',
  groups: [],
  category: '',
  description: '',
  minimalScore: 80,
  previewPNG: '',
  level: 5,
  gain: 5,
  fromDate: new Date(),
  toDate: new Date(),
  totalSlides: 20,
  stars: 3,
  averageStars: 4,
  comments: 15,
  groupsHistoric: [],
} as ITraining;

const trainingResults = {
  id: 'ZDqzqg',
  version: 1,
  trainingID: 'xSOvDC6vpZTzVqXy5owQ',
  userID: 'qdZDZDqg',
  groupsIDs: [],
  date: new Date(),
  time: 10,
  score: 10,
  validated: true,
  finished: true,
  currentStep: 4,
} as IAttempt;

fdescribe('ModalResultTrainingComponent', () => {
  let component: ModalResultTrainingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalResultTrainingComponent>;
  let opinionsService: OpinionsService;
  let dialogService: DialogService;
  let userService: UserService;
  let router: Router;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ModalResultTrainingComponent],
      providers: [EntityService, OpinionsService, UserService, NbAclService],
      imports: [FireModule, RouterModule.forRoot([]), NbThemeModule.forRoot(), NbDialogModule.forRoot(), NbAuthModule.forRoot()],

    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalResultTrainingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    opinionsService = TestBed.inject(OpinionsService);
    userService = TestBed.inject(UserService);
    dialogService = TestBed.inject(DialogService);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    component.training = training;
    component.results = trainingResults;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

modal-result-training.component.ts

the begin of modal

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IOpinion } from '@core/models/opinion.model';
import { IUser } from '@core/models/user.model';
import { DialogService } from '@core/services/dialog.service';
import { UserService } from '@core/services/user.service';
import { NbDialogRef, NbGlobalPhysicalPosition, NbToastrService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { OpinionsService } from 'app/feature/elearning-training/services/opinions.service';
import { cleanObject } from 'app/shared/utils';
import { first, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IAttempt } from '../../models/attempt.model';
import { ITraining } from '../../models/training.model';
/**
 * A modal to displays the training results when it's complete.
 *
 * @export
 * @class ResultTrainingComponent
 * @implements {OnInit}
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-modal-result-training',
  templateUrl: './modal-result-training.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-result-training.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalResultTrainingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() results: IAttempt;
  @Input() training: ITraining;
  public validated = false;
  public opinionForm: FormGroup;
  public selectedStars = 0;
  public hasAlreadyComment = true;
  public percentageScore: number;

  constructor(
    private opinionsService: OpinionsService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private ref: NbDialogRef<ModalResultTrainingComponent>,
    private router: Router,
    private toastrService: NbToastrService,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private dialogService: DialogService
  ) {}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: how do run tests ? `npm run test` ? What is your Angular version ?

Comment: hello, for run I use "ng test" and the version of my angular is 12.

Comment: It looks like a generic error. Don't you see any more relevent info in the stacktrace ? I often see "reading myVarName" in the stacktrace, that would mean he is trying to do "myVarName.settings". Also, I don't think you can import the Router in a test. There must be a mock for it I guess ? Can you make your own mocks, using `jasmine.createSpyObj('router', ['aRouterFunctionIHaveToUse', 'anOtherRouterFunctioniHaveToUse']);`, and inject it using the 'provide/useValue' syntax.

Comment: yeah, not really helping... Try to mock every service being in the constructor, and try again.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help , I will try :)